# find multiple whitespaces in string

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm trying to find all white spaces in string defined by begining as "jpeg" and ending with 600), in order to replace them with "_"
but how do I catch all the \s in the string?

I'm working on sublime text editor / notepad++

I tried:

```
^jpeg.*(\s).*600\)$
```

Thanks for the help
Example of text that is being edited:

```
# CHART: Share of persons living at risk of poverty or social exclusion ====
df <- S3R0004_M3080242 %>% 
        mutate(LAIKOTARPIS=parse_date_time(LAIKOTARPIS, "y")) 
jpeg("./figures/Share of persons living at risk of poverty or social exclusion.jpeg", width = 9, height = 6, units = 'in', res = 600)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=LAIKOTARPIS, y=obsValue)+
```

Comment: please keep the expected output too

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example? Please include all packages you use.

Comment: Also, it seems your code is not complete in the `ggplot` line.

Comment: Could you please clarify:  Are you trying to do this in the find/replace dialog of sublimetext3 (code editor) or write R code to replace text you've read into a variable?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions HTH

Comment: I'm trying to edit the R code in sublime text editor with search and replace. 
The names of the jpeg file should not contain any white-space, else I get problems with including them in latex.
Therefore the fullness of the R code is not necessary, as i only intend to replace the whitespaces in lines such as 
{jpeg("./figures/Share of persons living at risk of poverty or social exclusion.jpeg", width = 9, height = 6, units = 'in', res = 600)}

Comment: What is the expected result? `jpeg("./figures/Share_of_persons_living_at_risk_of_poverty_or_social_exclusion.jpeg", width = 9, height = 6, units = 'in', res = 600)`

Comment: Try `(?:\G(?!\A)|jpeg\("(?=[^"]*"[^)]*600\)))[^\s"]*\K\s+` and replace with `_`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zlQJHp/1).

Comment: Any feedback???

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew it worked and saved hell lot of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

*Find what*:      `(?:\G(?!\A)|jpeg\("(?=[^"]*"[^)]*600\)))[^\s"]*\K\s+`
*Replace With*: `_`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zlQJHp/1).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|jpeg\("(?=[^"]*"[^)]*600\)))` - matches either

  - `\G(?!\A)` - the end of the preceding match
  - `|` - or
  - `jpeg\("(?=[^"]*"[^)]*600\))` - `jpeg("` followed with any 0+ chars other than `"` (with `[^"]*`), then `"` and then any 0+ chars other than `)` and then `600)`
- `[^\s"]*` - matches and consumes 0+ chars other than whitespace and `"`
- `\K` - match reset operator, the text matched before is cleared from the match buffer
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (they will be replaced).